# How to configure a access_token can access which protected resource?

Tags: access-token, spring-security-oauth2

First of all, let's see the spec [Access Token Scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) ,it show that :

> The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-
> delimited, case-sensitive strings.  The strings are defined by the
> authorization server.

What's the value of access token scope definded in Spring Security OAuth  2.0.3.RELEASE? Is Only "read","write" or "trust" etc? Can the scope Associated with resource server?

You can see [github oauth api](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)

Comment: I don't really understand what you need. Can't you just inject the `Principal` into your controller method (and cast to `OAuth2Authentication`)?

Comment: I'm guessing "article_inf_api" is a misprint, and what you really need is a 403 (not a 500) because the resource id does not match the audience of the token. What version of Spring OAuth are you using, and how do you set up the resource servers to decode tokens?

Comment: That all looks fine. Can you be more specific about what it is that isn't working? (Might be a good idea to upgrade spring oauth as well BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes are just strings so you can use any value you like ("read" "write" etc. are just examples in the samples). Their meaning is a contract between the Authorization Server and the Resource Servers.